# Identifying git Object by Enumerated List Number during git gc

Tags: git

Background:
I have a very large repo on which I'm working on reducing the size (there are binary files in there that shouldn't be there).  One of my symptoms that the repo is too large is that I'm getting an "error: failed to run repack" during git gc.  The failure comes at 238511/253735 which I assume is the object count.

Question:
How do I find out what object 238511 refers?  I assume I can only inspect an object by providing the SHA ref to the object so how do I go from 238511 of 253735 to the SHA?

Comment: You can't; it's just an internal count of how many objects it's gotten through so far, in whatever order it is going through them, which isn't well defined. If you want to find *large* objects, there are several StackOverflow answers about that.